# Grid navigation

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you're on a 4 × 4 grid and want to go from the bottom left to the top left. How many different paths can you take? You are only allowed to move up-down-left-right (not diagonally) and MUST pass through every square only once.

A thought: Let's say we move L, R, U, D. It must be L=R (since we end up in the same column) and also U-D=3, if this is of any help. Obviously the total number of moves must be 14. For example, LLLLLLRRRRRRUUU or RRRRLLLLUUUUDD in any order.
Then we have to apply the restrictions, that we can't have, for example, RLR or LRL or UDU or DUD because this way we would pass through the same square twice.

I am stuck!

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://ac.els-cdn.com/0012365X9500330Y/1-s2.0-0012365X9500330Y-main.pdf?_tid=2cc052f7-5541-4d5e-8b38-3b06ed62bbc6&acdnat=1519988948_903894c59e8ad656f6ee4f30f0de8bd1

Comment: If you can pass through a square more than once and backtracking is allowed isn't it infinitely many?

Comment: I made a mistake: indeed, we are only allowed to pass through a square only once. I will correct the wording! Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Additionally, if the a condition is set on squares themselves, I would construct the graph of squares (rather than dealing with edges) and find my path on that, then consider how many ways to go from one square to another, but this is just a back of the envelope approach, take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Do you _have_ to pass through each square?

Comment: Yes you have to pass through each square.

Comment: I believe the first arrangement LLLLLLRRRRRRUUU only has 1 option: RRRULLLURRRULLL. The second one RRRRLLLLUUUUDD, has the following restrictions: We can only start with R or U. R can't be followed by L, L can't be followed by R, U can't be followed by D and D can't be followed by U. Also we must take into account the boundaries, that is, in the second move we can't have D or L and so on.